# How to view bytes as char in Watch window (Visual Studio 2017)?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to view a byte(s) during debugging as char when it is added to the watch list? There is an option to view as hexadecimal but none for char.

Comment: You would need to tell the debugger [what encoding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) that byte array is in before it could infer chars. So create a [watch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019#use-expressions-in-a-watch-window) that gets a [string in the correct encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8) out of the array.

Comment: I didn’t consider the encoding. That makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@GSerg stated the answer in the comments, but it would be better if it was put in an answer.

If you have a variable `char []buffer`, you can watch it as a `string` if you specify the correct [encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8#properties) and wrap the buffer with a call to [`GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8).  For example, if the encoding was `UTF8`, you would use in the watch window:

```cs
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
```